# MySQL return multiple rows with multiple joins and multiple sums

Tags: mysql, join, sum, rows

Thanks to everyone that has gotten me this far! The following works, but I cannot figure out how to return more than 1 row including all of the current column names. I understand that the way the statement is currently written, it is SUPPOSED to only return one row. However, I've tried several sub query examples but my sum columns always seem to be left out of the result. Any help would be awesome and thanks.

```
    SELECT 
club.id,
club.name,
club.status,
users.firstname,
users.lastname,
users.rights,
 SUM( job.status > '0' ) AS total,
 SUM( job.status = '1' ) AS incomplete,
 SUM( job.status = '2' ) AS pending,
 SUM( job.status = '3' ) AS live,
 SUM( job.status = '4' ) AS closed 
FROM club 
LEFT JOIN surveys 
ON job.club_id = club.id 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON users.id = job.users_id 
WHERE job.status > 0
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What are you expecting to see versus what are you actually seeing?

Comment: Multiple rows, I cannot figure out how to do a subquery that includes the sum Columns (ie. total, incomplete, pending, live, closed). I can get a single row with all data above, but when I try to format into a subqueries I get the multiple rows but no (total, incomplete, pending, live, closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you're going for, but here's a basic problem: you don't have a GROUP BY statement.  When you use a grouping function like SUM, it tells mysql that you want to group results together.  If you leave out GROUP BY, it groups everything into one row.  If you want to have one row per user (I assume so, because you're selecting their names), you should say

```
GROUP BY users.id
```

at the end of the query.

If this doesn't get you the results you are looking for, please post an example of what results you are looking for using fake data, and I can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: WOW how entirely stupid I feel right now, GROUP BY was the answer. Thanks a bunch. Apparently I fell into the trap of looking at a problem for so long, I left out what should have been obvious.